# How to group by a new string in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Here is some code I have written. The variable aa has a set of values that are not distinct. I would like for aa to be a set of distinct values so I need a "group by". The problem I have is that the "new" variable is a string created on the fly and I cannot group by it before I have done the new.

```
List<KeyValuePair<String, int>> x = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
x.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, int>("one", 1));
x.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, int>("two", 2));

List<KeyValuePair<String, int>> y = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
y.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, int>("one", 1));
y.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, int>("xxx", 12));

var aa = from xx in x
         from yy in y
         select new { AA = string.Format("a={0}, b={1}", xx, yy) };
```

Comment: So what are you expecting the result to be? And why are you creating an anonymous type for a single property? And why not just do any creation you need to do *in* the grouping part? You can then take the key of any group.

Comment: You say you want **distinct** things but talk about *group by* and not [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx), why ?

Comment: Hello Jon. I would like the result to be the same as it is now (this is just a made up example and the real code is much more complicated and would contain around 60 objects), so 4 objects. If this was SQL I would go SELECT DISTINCT * FROM aa

Comment: Hi Sehnsucht, I use DISTINCT and GROUP BY interchangeably as they are the same thing to me in this problem, eg. "SELECT DISTINCT something FROM aa" vs. "SELECT something FROM aa GROUP BY something" are the same.

Comment: Why are you creating an anonymous variable with one property that is a string created from two values? Why not just create `new { xx, yy }`?

Answer (score 0):

Could use `Distinct()`

```
//This var can be exchanged with IEnumerable<string> 
var aa = (from xx in x
          from yy in y
          select string.Format("a={0}, b={1}", xx, yy))
          .Distinct();
```

if you want to make list x's content excusive over y and or y's content exclusive over x the you have the command `Except()`

```
var aa1 = from xx in x
         from yy in y
         select new { AA = string.Format("a={0}, b={1}", xx, yy) };
/*RESULT:
a=[one, 1], b=[one, 1]
a=[one, 1], b=[xxx, 12]
a=[two, 2], b=[one, 1]
a=[two, 2], b=[xxx, 12]*/

var aa2 = from xx in x
         from yy in y.Except(x)
         select new { AA = string.Format("a={0}, b={1}", xx, yy) };
/*RESULT:
a=[one, 1], b=[xxx, 12]
a=[two, 2], b=[xxx, 12]*/

var aa3 = from xx in x.Except(y)
         from yy in y
         select new { AA = string.Format("a={0}, b={1}", xx, yy) };
/*RESULT:
a=[two, 2], b=[one, 1]
a=[two, 2], b=[xxx, 12]*/

var aa4 = from xx in x.Except(y)
         from yy in y.Except(x)
         select new { AA = string.Format("a={0}, b={1}", xx, yy) };
/*RESULT:
a=[two, 2], b=[xxx, 12]*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can you can materialize with aa.ToList() and then group by. But you should at least say what do you expect as output